# Why doesn't my if statement work with (red || green || blue) > 255

Tags: java

here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RGBColor
{
    // instance variables
    private int _red;
    private int _green;
    private int _blue;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class RGBColor
     */
    public RGBColor()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        _red=_green=_blue=0;
    }
    public RGBColor(int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        if(((red || green || blue) > 255)  || ((red || green || blue) < 0))
        red=_green=_blue=0;
        else
        {
        _red = red;
        _green = green;
        _blue = blue;
    }
    }
    public RGBColor(RGBColor other)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter 3 integers which will represent colors: ");
        System.out.println("First one, RED.");
        Scanner getColors = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Second one, GREEN.");
        Scanner getGreen = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Third one, BLUE.");
        Scanner getBlue = new Scanner(System.in);



}
public int getRed()
{
    return _red;
}
public int getGreen()
{
    return _green;
}
public int getBlue()
{
    return _blue;
}
public void setRed(int num)
{
    if(((red || green || blue) > 255)  || ((red || green || blue) < 0))
    break;
    else
    _red = num;
} 
public void setGreen(int num)
{
    _green = num;
}
public void setBlue(int num)
{
    blue_ = num;
}
}
```

I'm having problems in this line:

```
if(((red || green || blue) > 255)  || ((red || green || blue) < 0))
```

bad operand types for binary operator ||. Any ideas how to fix it? My code is very simple so I believe I don't have to explain anything. I just don't understand why I can't check if integer is greater than 255 for e.g. Thanks on advance!

Comment: You've got some weird variables going on with _red etc. That's not very conventional in java. You should consider making them just red, green, blue etc. Then when you reference them in RGBColor where you are passing in red you just need to denote that they're the variables from this class. So you end up with this.red = red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test each variable seperately:

```
if(red > 255 || green > 255 || blue > 255 || red < 0 || green < 0 || blue < 0)
```

However, for good code I'd write a function:

```
private static boolean anyNotValid(int... values) {
    for(int i: values) {
        if(i < 0 || i > 255) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

... which you could then call as:

```
if(anyNotValid(red, green, blue))
```

Answer (score 1):

red, green and blue are integers and you should check separately not with OR operation.. you can use OR operation for boolean variables

e.g

```
red > 255 || green > 255 || blue > 255
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare all three things at once in a single comparison like this:

```
(red || green || blue) > 255
```

You have to separate them into separate comparisons.

```
red > 255 || green > 255 || blue > 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do it like this:

```
if (!isWithinBounds(red, green, blue)) {
   ...
}
```

And create this method:

```
private static boolean isWithinBounds(int... values) {
    boolean withinBounds = values.length > 0;
    for (int value : values) {
        withinBounds &= value > 0 && value < 256;
    }
    return withinBounds;
}
```